# PageSetup.RightFooter text remains after switching to PageSetup.CenterFooter

Tags: excel, vba

I changed the code for the footer of my PDF from `.RightFooter = "Page &P of &N"` to `.CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"`.

Now the "Page &P of &N" shows in the center and on the right even though the `.RightFooter` is no longer there.

I have deleted the Module and recreated it. I have restarted my PC thinking it was hung in memory.

Here's my code.

```
Sub Set_PrintRnag()
Dim LstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim strDesktop As String

strDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

LstRw = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("R1:S" & LstRw)

With Sheet2.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "&C &B &20 Cohort List Report:" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
End With

Rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strDesktop & "\CohortList " & " " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your right footer appear in print preview?  Go to page setup and check to see if there is a 'Right Section' within the Custom Footer section.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The PDF is created when I run the code. There's not an opportunity to Preview. The code runs and the PDF is rendered as is. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding. Thank you for your response.

Comment: What I mean is within Excel directly.  My thought is the Excel document itself has a footer, so even though you're effectively managing other footers via VBA, another header may already exist.  i.e. go to page setup within Excel, then check for footers there.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. Had to use .RightFooter = "".